# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot process ISO 14443-4 tag because AID was not set

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, nfc, smartcard

I'm running an electron application with the nfc-pcsc module. When I hold my Android device close to the acr-122u, I get the following logging:

```
Running in development
18:52:19 – info: nfc module init
(node:30973) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot process ISO 14443-4 tag because AID was not set.
    at ACR122Reader.handle_Iso_14443_4_Tag (/private/var/www/lab/electron-clientnfc/node_modules/nfc-pcsc/dist/Reader.js:566:26)
    at ACR122Reader.handleTag (/private/var/www/lab/electron-clientnfc/node_modules/nfc-pcsc/dist/Reader.js:506:21)
    at CardReader.Reader.reader.on (/private/var/www/lab/electron-clientnfc/node_modules/nfc-pcsc/dist/Reader.js:164:18)
(node:30973) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:30973) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

This is my code:

```
const { NFC } = require('nfc-pcsc');

const nfc = new NFC(); // optionally you can pass logger

nfc.on('reader', (reader) => {

  console.log(`${reader.reader.name}  device attached`);

  reader.aid = 'F222222222';

   reader.on('card', async card => {
    console.log(`${reader.reader.name}  card detected`, card);
  });

  reader.on('card.off', (card) => {
    console.log(`${reader.reader.name}  card removed`, card);
  });

  reader.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(`${reader.reader.name}  an error occurred`, err);
  });

  reader.on('end', () => {
    console.log(`${reader.reader.name}  device removed`);
  });
});

nfc.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log('an error occurred', err);
});
```

what is wrong with this?